# Remove only side 3 and 4 from a plot in base plot

Tags: r, plot

I would like to remove only the top (side 3) and right-hand (side 4) borders of a plot in base plot. All of the advice that I can find calls for setting

```
axis = F
```

however, I am then forced to redraw the x and y axis and manually add the labels. Is there a more direct way to ask R to simply not plot side 3 and 4 in base plot?

Comment: You probably want `bty = "l"`. That's a lowercase L, as in the shape of the axes you want to keep (as opposed to C, N, U, ]), etc. See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly! Thanks very much!

Comment: @Thomas Why don't you post that as an answer? Maybe with a nice graphic. The [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/removing-borders-in-r-plots-for-achieving-tuftes-axis) question is not a dupe. Oh, it's not `"N"`, it's `"n"`. You can even add the undocumented feature that for the others both the documented lowercase and undocumented uppercase work but **not for `"n"`**. And there is also `"7"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "box" around a plot is a separate graphical element from the axes, so this can be difficult to figure out because you can omit the axes entirely but still have a visible box. The presence and shape of the box is dictated by the `bty` (or "box type") graphical parameter, which you can set inside your plot call or using [the `par()` global graphical parameter function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html).

There are several allowed values of `bty`: "o" (the default), "l", "7", "c", "u", "]", or "[". These correspond to the shape of the box so you have to take them literally. "n" suppresses the box.

```
# create some data
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
x <- rnorm(n)
y <- rnorm(n)

# demonstrate values of `par`
## with axes
layout(matrix(1:8, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE))
lapply(c("o", "l", "7", "c", "u", "[", "]", "n"), function(arg) {
  plot(x, y, bty = arg, main = sprintf("bty = '%s'", arg))
})
```

[image: Examples of 'bty' with axes]

```
## without axes
dev.off()
layout(matrix(1:8, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE))
lapply(c("o", "l", "7", "c", "u", "[", "]", "n"), function(arg) {
  plot(x, y, bty = arg, main = sprintf("bty = '%s'", arg), xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")
})
```

[image: Examples of 'bty' without axes]